# Converting Treeset (object []) into an int[] array?

Tags: java, hashset, return-type, treeset

I am making a method to sort using Hashset/Treeset, however I am stopped when it comes to taking my Treeset and trying to return it back from the method. I know I could change the return type to Object[], but I was wondering if there was any way to keep the return type as an int[].

```
static int[] sortArrayWithHashset(int array[]) {
    HashSet<Integer> myHashSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i > array.length;i++) {
        myHashSet.add(array[i]);
    }

    TreeSet<Integer> myTreeSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    myTreeSet.addAll(myHashSet);
    //array = myTreeSet.toArray();
    return array;
}
```

Comment: "Hashset would be the best option (Note that HashSet insert and lookup O(1))." in regards to why I am attempting a sort as such (for an O(n) runtime).

Comment: "for an O(n)" - I'm afraid you misunderstand the essentials of sorting algorithms. TreeSet uses a so-called red-black tree under the hood. Time-complexity for sorting that you get by utilizing TreeSet is O(n log n). It's possible to sort the data in a linear time, but only in some specific cases.

Answer (score 3):

To convert a collection into an array you can either use Stream IPA or create an array manually and populate it inside a loop.

```
public static int[] collectionToIntArray(Collection<Integer> source) {
        return source.stream()
                .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                .toArray();
    }
```

```
public static int[] collectionToIntArray(Collection<Integer> source) {
        int[] result = new int[source.size()];
        int pos = 0;
        for (int next: source) {
            result[pos++] = next;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The code you've provided is slightly contrived. There are things you need to be aware of:

- Set will discard all duplicates from the source array;
- you can add array elements into a TreeSet directly;
- write your code against interfaces not against class, that provides more flexibility, like that

```
    Set<Integer> myHashSet = new HashSet<>();
    NavigableSet<Integer> myTreeSet = new TreeSet<>();
```

- Lastly, I guess you were practicing in order to get familiar with the Set interface implementations and hence didn't aim for this code to be efficient. To complete to overall picture it is worth reminding that to sort an array you can simply use **Arrays.sort()**.

Answer (score 0):

To get an `int[]`, what you must to is to write

```
myTreeSet.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same without a `Set` using `streams`:

```
public static int[] sortArray(int[] array) {
    return Arrays.stream(array).sorted().toArray();
}
```

Comment: Or just use `Collections.sort` -- you don't even need streams for this.

Comment: @yshavit `Collections.sort` doesn't sort `arrays`, only `Collections`. You could use `Arrays.sort`, but I assumed that the OP needed a new instance of the `array`.

Comment: Erm sorry, you're right -- I meant `Arrays`. There's also `Arrays.copyOf`, which you can combine with `sort` if you want to sort a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

You code has a few bugs, for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i > array.length;i++) {...}
```

This will cause and endless loop, correctly should be: `i < array.length`. In fact this `for` loop can be transformed into an enhanced `for`, such as:

```
HashSet<Integer> myHashSet = new HashSet<>();
for (int a : array) {
    myHashSet.add(a);
}
```

If we think about, this `HashSet` is not really needed, since we can add everything directly to the `TreeSet`.

Moving on, the problem with using `toArray` and expecting to have an array with primitive integers, will not work. The reason for this is that collections in Java can store types which inherit `Object`. To be able to store primitive, we have boxed types, such as `Integer`, `Double`, etc. which wrap their primitive. So, if we want to use `toArray`, one option would be to return an array with `Integers`:

```
static Integer[] sortArrayWithHashset(int[] array) {
    Set<Integer> myTreeSet = new TreeSet<>();
    for (int a : array) {
        myTreeSet.add(a);
    }

    return myTreeSet.toArray(new Integer[array.length]);
}
```

If we want to return an array of primitive integers, we can use streams to unbox the values, such as:

```
static int[] sortArrayWithHashset(int[] array) {
    Set<Integer> myTreeSet = new TreeSet<>();
        for (int a : array) {
            myTreeSet.add(a);
        }

    return myTreeSet.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
}
```

Comment: In fact this `for (int i = 0; i > array.length; i++) {…}` creates a loop that stops immediately. Zero will never be greater than any non-negative number. 